# How to send post request through swiftUI in iOS 16.0?

Tags: swift

Hey guys I am trying to use the face++ API to detect human body in a picture, but I keep getting 400 bad request. I think there is something wrong with my request code, but I am not sure where. For test, I host a picture on a third-party website just want to know how to get the request right. I will delete the api key later in case someone use it improperly.

```
private func requestFacePlusAPI() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api-cn.faceplusplus.com/humanbodypp/v1/detect")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
    
    
    let api_key = "TpDqYnF1c5xe_iQzaBkVGkAqflqS3aCP"
    let api_secret = "JsDx4hiQUOSXuus8MV21WB4F5YzQnB4B"
    guard model.ImageData != nil else { return }
    let image_base64 = model.ImageData!.base64EncodedData()
    print(model.ImageData!)
    print(image_base64)
    let data = FacePlusData(api_key: api_key, api_secret: api_secret, image_url: "https://i.postimg.cc/prz1VKTY/Wechat-IMG2.jpg")
    guard let uploadData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(data) else {
        return
    }
    let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, from: uploadData) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print ("error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
            print (response)
            print ("server error")
            return
        }
        if let mimeType = response.mimeType,
            mimeType == "application/json",
            let data = data,
            let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print ("got data: \(dataString)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()

}
```

Comment: API address
https://console.faceplusplus.com/documents/10880589

Comment: SwiftUI has no bearing on a post request...

Comment: You don't use `image_base64`? `setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "multipart/form-data")` That's quite strange... Usually that would be both `value` of a header field...

Comment: That's right, got this one fixed

Comment: @Larme Anything else? I did not use the image_base64 because I am not sure whether I encode it correctly. For safe purpose, I just use the URL link, which I tested I can get the picture through the link.

Comment: Also, add before the `guard let response`: `if let data = data, print("Response strinigified: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")`

Comment: @Larme It is giving "got data: Optional("{\"error_message\":\"MISSING_ARGUMENTS: api_key\"}\n")" but I encode the api_key already. Seems like the JSONEncoder() did not work?

Comment: It should have worked, else you would have hit the `return` of the `guard let`... You can still add `print("Sending: \(String(data: uploadData, encoding: .utf8)")` to be sure...

Comment: But seeing how the `cURL` is made on the doc, I'm wondering if it's not expecting URL encoding parameters only and not JSON...:  `uploadData = Data("apiKey=\(api_key)& api_secret=\(apiSecret)&image_url="...".utf8)` instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the documentation and the cURL sample:

```
curl -X POST "https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/humanbodypp/beta/detect" -F "api_key=<api_key>" \
-F "api_secret=<api_secret>" \
-F "image_file=@image_file.jpg" \
-F "return_attributes=gender"
```

You need to send parameters in "URL Encoded Form":

```
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
...
let uploadData = Data("api_key=\(api_key)&api_secret=\(api_secret)&image_url=https://i.postimg.cc/prz1VKTY/Wechat-IMG2.jpg".utf8)
```

Comment: worked. lol!!!!!!